# Inlcuding AMD javascript as non-AMD results in library is undefined in all sorts of DOM waiting mechanisms

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, requirejs, amd

Trying to create an AMD Javascript library to be included in non-AMD projects. Here's my setup:

app.coffee

```
define ->

class App

    constructor: -> console.log 'instantiating App'

    init: -> console.log 'Init called'
```

index.html

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dev-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('doc', window.app);
    });

    $(function(){
        console.log('func', window.app);
    });

    window.onload = function()
    {
        console.log('onload', window.app);
    }

</script></body>
```

main.js

```
require(['cs!app'], function(app){
  return window.app = new app;
});
```

I am building this project with r.js optimizer to get dev-latest.js as the output. Here's my build file (PS: Build is successful):

```
({
    baseUrl: './vendor',

    paths: {

        app: '../app',
        'require-lib': 'require'
    },

    name: '../main',

    out: 'dev-latest.js',

    include: 'require-lib',

    preserveLicenseComments: false

})
```

When running the code in the browser here's the output:

```
doc undefined
func undefined
onload undefined
instantiating App dev-latest.js:1
app.init(); // running this manually in the browser console
Init called
```

How should I go about this and get app to load before being used ?

Answer (score 0):

Using AMD you cant rely on a module being created outside of a module. The only reliable way is to load the result of a module into another module. So in your case need to create a new module which then can lsiten to `$.read`:

```
define( [App], (App)-> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('doc', App);
   });
)
```

Comment: Not sure where this is supposed to happen, App is an undefined variable.. or am I missing something ?

Answer (score -1):

Solved it by using [browserify](http://browserify.org) (just found about it) which uses the CommonJS form of dependency loading and saves all that clutter. Also a great template for starting projects is [amitayd's grunt-browserify-jasmine setup](https://github.com/amitayd/grunt-browserify-jasmine-node-example)